# Scroll Chat to bottom when you hide the keyboard

Tags: android

So I'm working on a chat page and when I send some messages and after sending, when i hide the keyboard, the screen scrolls down the exact height that the keybaord was, and then I have to manually scroll till the last position.

The scroll works perfect when i have to type a new message but gives problem when keybaord is removed off the screen.

```
addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, bottom, _, _, _, oldBottom ->
        val y = oldBottom - bottom
        if (y.absoluteValue > 0) {
            post {
                if (y > 0 || verticalScrollOffset.get().absoluteValue >= y.absoluteValue) {
                    scrollBy(0, y)
                } else {
                    scrollBy(0, verticalScrollOffset.get())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code snippet for layoutChangeListener. Any help will be appreciated.

Activity has : **"adjustResize|stateHidden"** in the manifest.

have followed the same code as : https://medium.com/@aramaki/so-heres-the-thing-99d6d03daaf2